# How to choose the picture(Object) in Canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, events, canvas

I just want to start the process by clicking on the ball.gif. I couldn't do it. Also at the end of the animation my picture disappears.
Here are my codes;

Select the object in Canvas and add it to the event.
I looked at almost all the issues. But I didn't find the answer.

```
var player, mouse;
var iterations = 0;


var game = {
    canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
    start: function () {

        game.canvas.width = 357;
        game.canvas.height = 500;
        game.canvas.style.border = "1px solid red";
        game.ctx = game.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.appendChild(game.canvas);
        player=new game.nesne(150,400,50,50);

        game.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
            game.nesne(150,400,50,50);
        });

        game.timer = setInterval(game.animate.bind(this), 30);
    },
    draw: function () {

        player.draw();
    },
    update: function () {
    },
    nesne: function (x, y, w, h) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y; 
        this.w = w; 
        this.h = h; 

        this.image=new Image();
        this.image.src="ball.gif";
        this.vx = 1; 
        this.vy = -1; 
        this.draw = function () {

          game.ctx.drawImage(this.image,this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);


        }


        this.update = function () {
            this.x += this.vx; 
            this.y += this.vy; 

        }
    },

    animate: function () {
        game.ctx.clearRect(0,0,game.canvas.width,game.canvas.height);

        iterations++
    if (iterations >= 100)
        clearInterval(interval);
        game.update(); 
        game.draw(); 

    },
}
window.addEventListener("load", game.start, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Changes I've made:

1. instead of `clearInterval(interval);` I use `clearInterval(game.timer);`
   The `interval` is not defined. You have to use the handler you created for the `setInterval`(line 24 in my code)
2. You call the `game.update` function but in your code is an empty function. I've changed that. Now the `game.update()` calls the `player.update()`.
3. To reanimate the player again on `mousedown` you need to reset the `iterations = 0;`

```js
var player, mouse;
var iterations = 0;


var game = {
    canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
    start: function () {

        game.canvas.width = 357;
        game.canvas.height = 500;
        game.canvas.style.border = "1px solid red";
        game.ctx = game.canvas.getContext("2d");
      
      
        document.body.appendChild(game.canvas);
      
        player=new game.nesne(150,400,50,50);
        

        game.canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", 
       function(event) {
      
          if (game.timer) clearInterval(game.timer);
          game.nesne(150, 400, 50, 50);
          iterations = 0;
          game.timer = setInterval(game.animate.bind(this), 30);

         
        });

        game.timer = setInterval(game.animate.bind(this), 30);
    },
  
  
    draw: function () {
        player.draw();
    },
  
    update: function () {
      player.update();///////////////
    },
  
  
    nesne: function (x, y, w, h) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y; 
        this.w = w; 
        this.h = h; 

        this.image=new Image();
        this.image.src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/puppy150x150.jpg";
        this.vx = 1; 
        this.vy = -1; 
        this.draw = function () {

          game.ctx.drawImage(this.image,this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);


        }


        this.update = function () {
            this.x += this.vx; 
            this.y += this.vy; 

        }
    },

    animate: function () {
        game.ctx.clearRect(0,0,game.canvas.width,game.canvas.height);

        iterations++
    if (iterations >= 100)
        //clearInterval(interval);
        clearInterval(game.timer);
        game.update(); 
        game.draw(); 

    }
}

window.addEventListener("load", game.start, false);
```

#### UPDATE

The OP commented:

> So how do I do this when I just click on the picture.

In this case you need to detect the position of the mouse  when clicking the canvas. I've added a function to detect the mouse position:

```js
function oMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var ClientRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
}
}
```

Next you need to change the function for the `mousedown`. You need to use the method [isPointInPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) to check if the mouse is inside the `nesne` thing.

```js
function(event) {
mouse = oMousePos(game.canvas, event);
      
game.ctx.beginPath();
game.ctx.rect(player.x,player.y,player.w,player.h);
if (game.ctx.isPointInPath(mouse.x, mouse.y)) {
     
         
if (game.timer) clearInterval(game.timer);
game.nesne(150, 400, 50, 50);
iterations = 0;
game.timer = setInterval(game.animate.bind(this), 30);
}
         
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the changes you made. So how do I do this when I just click on the picture. And one of the things I can't do is I'm really freaking out :) –

Comment: The picture disappeared when I changed the codes according to ispointPath. I must have made a mistake again somewhere.Also in console console 22 says there is an error.                
            
mouse = oMousePos(game.canvas, event); ==> error code